# Typedef doesn't work after the first function definition?

Tags: c++, arduino, typedef

So I'm screwing around with some Arduino (IDE version 1.8.9, FWIW) code, and I've discovered that typedefs seem not to work if placed after a function definition. For example, the following sketch fails to compile with `error: 'foo' does not name a type`, but if you delete the first line there's no issue.

```
bool baz() { return false; }
typedef uint32_t foo;
foo bar() { return 1; }

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Is this some nuance of how typedef works that I'm not familiar with, some Arduino-specific oddness, or is it just a bug?

(Note that the specific choice of `uint32_t` doesn't matter here; the same behavior occurs with any type.)

Comment: Did you include `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`? https://ideone.com/83ZhCn

Comment: Tried it both ways, same result. Arduino doesn't require that include typically, as evidenced by it working fine if you drop the first line. Also other types (like, say, `int`) behave the same.

Comment: AFAIK, Arduino IDE doesn't let you do "real" C++, it is more or less some sub-dialect of C++.

Comment: @OznOg IDK about that... it uses gcc. There's no STL included, but those are just headers and you can add them if you want, though you'd probably want an optimized version. I've even used portions of Boost in the Arduino IDE before. (Granted, building for an ESP8266, but still.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arduino toolchain includes a preprocessor that attempts to make writing C++ easier.  One of the things Arduino's preprocessor does is insert declarations for all of the functions in your sketch at the top of the file.  That means that the actual C++ code passed to g++ looks like this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#line 1 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
#line 1 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
#line 1 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
bool baz();
#line 3 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
foo bar();
#line 5 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
void setup();
#line 10 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
void loop();
#line 1 "E:\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jun16a\\sketch_jun16a.ino"
bool baz() { return false; }
typedef uint32_t foo;
foo bar() { return 1; }

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

As you can see, `foo bar();` is declared before the name `foo` is introduced by your `typedef`.

To work around this, add your own declaration of `bar`.  Arduino's preprocessor will only add declarations of functions that you haven't declared yourself:

```
bool baz() { return false; }
typedef uint32_t foo;
foo bar();
foo bar() { return 1; }

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

---

As for why this isn't an issue when the `typedef` is the first line of the sketch: it looks like Arduino's preprocessor lifts `typedef` and `using` declarations along with existing function declarations and class definitions up to the top of the file, before the function declarations it adds, but only if they appear before any function definitions (not counting class member functions defined inline in the class definition).

Comment: Why would removing the first line make it work, though?

Comment: Oh that's simply horrible.  (At least, horrible to claim "you're writing C++").   @Reid, presumably the extra non-standard preprocessor inserts the forward declarations just ahead of the first function body, so with the first line they end up before the typedef, otherwise they end up after it.

Comment: Added a bit about that.  Looks like it lifts `typedef` and `using` declarations up along with the function declarations it adds, but only if they appear before any function definitions.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's not "C++", it's "INO" :) The idea, as I understand it, that Arduino can concatenate all the .ino sketches and compile them as one compilation unit. If you write your code as proper C++, in .h headers or in .cpp compilation units, it should compile and work properly.

Comment: @Kit: The code shown is (apart from missing `#include <stdint.h>` or `#include <inttypes.h>`) fully standard C++, and apparently is broken by this extra preprocessor.

Comment: Well, that's retarded. I can't imagine the rationale, if it was a conscious decision at all. I guess I'll just rename the file to .pde or something.